# THREE.JS 2d geometry drawing WebGL

Tags: three.js, webgl, shapes

Can someone please give a simple demonstration how to draw a rectangle or a path in a 2d word via THREE.js.

Why want i use TGREE.JS (a 3D framework) for my >>2D<< Puzzle game? I have tried SVG, and Canvas but i had performance issue (on mobile). I have tried WebGL via Pixi.js (a 2D WebGL framework) and my tests (panning an zooming 5000 rectangles with 60+fps) were good, but it lacks of path drawing.

My idea to load the SVG paths / Cufon paths, show them in 2D and use the power of WebGL. (Imagine a map with custom font (lots of vector based shapes) which can be pan and zoom without any quality loss... oh yeah -- on mobile)

Comment: Did you look at the three.js examples? http://threejs.org/examples/canvas_geometry_shapes.html http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_geometry_shapes.html

Answer (score -1):

Found this within the web....

http://www.lab4games.net/zz85/blog/2014/09/08/rendering-lines-and-bezier-curves-in-three-js-and-webgl/

Comment: It would be best if you added a few words explaining what to expect under the link. E.g. "here's an example how to draw lines and Bezier curves on HTML canvas". The reader would have easier time understanding your comment.